# pass local.properties in build.gradle android through Git Hub secret

Tags: android, continuous-integration, building-github-actions

I am trying to automate build process of android app, I have stored baseUrl in local.properties file, and passing file content through Github secret, but Github action is keep failing,

build.gradle:

```
    def propFile=rootProject.file("./local.properties")
    def properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

    def baseUrl = properties['BASEURL']
    //getProperty("BASEURL", "")


    debug {
        buildConfigField 'String', "BASEURL", baseUrl
        resValue 'string', "base_url", baseUrl
    }
```

YML:

```
name: Android CI

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Decode BASEURL
      env:
        BASEURL: ${{ secrets.BASEURL }}
      run: echo BASEURL="$BASEURL" > ./local.properties


    - name: Clean
      run: ./gradlew clean
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build
```

How i am passing BASEURL through Github secret

[image]

This is log output from Github action Console

[image]

Comment: You have probably placed `local.properties` not at the root of your project when you created it in github actions. Can you do `echo BASEURL="$BASEURL" > ./local.properties`, can you also run `ls -al` to see the layout of the files

Comment: i checked local.properties file is in root of the project, @smac89

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem, I was passing wrongly argument from Github secret, it should be like

```
\"http://fakeapi.com"\
```

and also i was doing wrong in action file, instead of ./gradlew build it should be

```
./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace
```

then only it will invoke below part from build.gradle and  replace the BaseUrl with new value from local.properties

```
debug {
            buildConfigField 'String', "BASEURL", baseUrl
            resValue 'string', "base_url", baseUrl
        }
```

I also used https://github.com/juliangruber/read-file-action to see the content of the local.properties and verified everything is fine in this file or not.

Comment: it does seem to be like \"http://fakeapi.com\" ??? (please note the ' "\ ' in the answer).

Answer (score 0):

I used below command and its worked . Don't need to consider `\`

```
run: echo 'apiKey=${{ secrets.API_KEY }}' > ./local.properties
```

And secret key `API_KEY` value was stored like `"*******"`