# Android -- Changing local.properties with Github Actions and Gradle -- nullable value issue

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, yaml, github-actions

I have been trying to replace local.properties values via Github actions. There are a good few tutorials online, but I seem to be getting the same error each time.

I followed this:
[pass local.properties in build.gradle android through Git Hub secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62278936/pass-local-properties-in-build-gradle-android-through-git-hub-secret#)

The issue is that I get the following error:

> Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.buildConfigField, parameter value

I attempted to get around this with an elvis operator like so:

```
 buildTypes {

    def propFile=rootProject.file("./local.properties")
    def properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

    def username = properties['MOCK_USERNAME']
    def password = properties['MOCK_PASSWORD']

    release {
        buildConfigField 'String', "USERNAME", username ?: "\"foo\""
        buildConfigField 'String', "PASSWORD", password ?: "\"foo\""

        resValue('string', "mock_username", username ?: "\"foo\"")
        resValue('string', "mock_password", password ?: "\"foo\"")
```

This succeeds but the value is always foo, rather than replaced by the actions yaml script:

```
on:
  push:

jobs:
  unit_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Make gradlew executable
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew
      - name: Update Username from Secrets
        env:
          MOCK_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USER }}
        run: echo MOCK_USERNAME="$MOCK_USERNAME" > ./local.properties
      - name: Update Password from Secrets
        env:
          MOCK_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
        run: echo MOCK_PASSWORD="$MOCK_PASSWORD" > ./local.properties

      - name: Assemble app debug APK
        run: bash ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace

      - name: Unit tests
        run: ./gradlew test
```

In all of the tutorials I have seen, nobody has to use the elvis operator or gets the nullable error. I am not sure why this is happening. The project itself is multi-module (an SDK and a sample application) so I wonder if it is not referencing local properties correctly?

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of below this line

```
run: echo MOCK_USERNAME="$MOCK_USERNAME" > ./local.properties
```

Use below line

```
run: echo 'MOCK_USERNAME=${{ secrets.USER }}' > ./local.properties
```

Apply this pattern for others secrets  too.